# load text into textarea from code behind in asp.net using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I've one asp.net page and I want to load text into the textArea control which is in aspx page from into a variable in code behind (C#):

Code behind:

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTextArea Output1 = 
    (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTextArea)(FindControl("textarea1"));       
Output1.Value = Output.ToString();
```

ASP:

```
<div style ="width: 78%; float: right; height: 85px; display: block;" 
    class="message_text_box_left">

    <textarea id="textarea1" name="textarea1" cols="30" rows="3" 
        class="message_text_box" title="Share your Idias here..." 
        tabindex="1" onkeyup="addrow_fun();"></textarea>                        
</div>
```

but it is giving error like

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: check if 'Output1' did have a value or is null which probably meant it wasn't able to find the control or the control doesn't exists.

Comment: Are you Finding the control at the right place if its within a panel or something you will need to Find it within that control (parent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the

```
runat="server"
```

attribute to the text area.

Or, preferable you should use the [`TextBox` ASP.NET control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.aspx) and set the [`TextMode` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textmode.aspx) to `TextBoxMode.MultiLine`. Example follows:

Code behind:

```
Output1.Text = Output.ToString();
```

ASP:

```
<div style ="width: 78%; float: right; height: 85px; display: block;" 
    class="message_text_box_left">

    <asp:TextBox ID="Output1" Rows="3" 
        CssClass="message_text_box" ToolTip="Share your ideas here..." 
        TextMode="MultiLine" />                        
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your respond. that i have alredy done, still getting error.

Comment: The `FindControl` method of the page you are calling is _not_ recursive. I.e. if your control is contained within other controls that have the `runat="server"` attribute set, `FindControl` returns `null`.

Comment: Yes But, it is return the error **Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText' to type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTextArea'.**

Comment: @user1230825 I've added an example.

Comment: No My Friend, I can not use asp control, I have to use only html textarea here.

Answer (score 1):

Add `runat="server"` in `*.aspx` file. Use `Innertext` property to set the text value.
E.g.

```
htmlTexarea.InnerHtml = "sample"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `runat="server"` to your control
2. Check your .designer.cs or codebehind .cs file for `textarea`/`textbox` declaration and fix it.
3. Do not use `FindControl` function (it is not recursive), get control by ID. `textarea1.Value = xxx;`

Answer (score 0):

Try casting to HTML generic control and set it's value or change it to use an asp textbox textmode= multiline

Answer (score 0):

If you add the runat="server" attribute you should be able to use the textarea1.innerText directly.

Answer (score 0):

Add runat="server" and get value with InnerText from code behind