# how I can read text from html textarea in asp.net page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I  set html textarea in asp.net page with out runat="server" and I need set the text in string variable by C# in code behind

Comment: Then add `runat="server"`.     It's not so bad ;)

Answer (score 2):

An ASP.NET TextBox control with the TextMode property set to MultiLine will generate an Html TEXTAREA control.

So instead of crafting Html TEXTAREA manually, you can just drop a TextBox control and have:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
```

and then in your code behind:

```
 TextBox2.Text = "... blah blah blah...";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Request.Form Collection http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985(v=vs.90).aspx  to retrieve values..

Comment: How does it help OP to set the textarea's value? The `HttpRequest.Form` collection is readonly(for logical reasons).

Comment: @Tim you are correct , it will retrieve values and question was to set it..My bad..

Comment: @tim then he can always set it via aspx via server variables right?

Comment: If he wants to access a control on serverside, he should make it a serverside control. Everything else would be pointless.

Comment: @tim yes , thats his requirement actually without a runat=server :) .Thanks for correcting me there.

Comment: @tim can't we use controls collection and modify the value?

Comment: HTML controls are not part of the page's control collection unless they aren't `runat="server"`. HTML elements in ASP.NET files are, by default, treated as text.

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9495428/load-text-into-textarea-from-code-behind-in-asp-net-using-c-sharp)

i think its the same, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I guess your trying to accomplish is to populate your textbox with the variable on the server side with out runat="server" set to the control.

You can do that with ajax and simple jquery.

Lets say your have this on your YourPage.aspx

```
<input id="txtMyTextBox" type="text" />
```

and next is a simple jquery

```
function getMytextValue() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/MainPage.aspx/YourServerSideFunction",
            type: "post",
            data: "{ }",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                //Get your value from JSON data.d;
                $('#txtMyTextBox').val(data.d);
            },
            error: function (request, status, err) {
                //Do something here for error;
            }
        });
    }
```

And now just call the jquery on what ever event you like.

PS: dont forget to create a [WebMethod] on your code behind.

Hope this help you! :D

Answer (score 0):

couldn't you just save the value to a variable in your codebehind file and then on the webform itself just reference the variable by some manner such as <%= varName =>??

The above seem like a lot of work just to reference a variable that you can set quite easily in C# and then pull in the page load.

Answer (score 0):

[Kindly review this link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-3-passing-viewdata-from-controllers-to-views)

You can set data in code behind by using ViewData and can access them in html as explained in above link.